# Increase and decrease check not working by 10, 100, 1000 and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to check if my input increases or decreases, this works fine except for the numbers 10, 100, 1000 and so on. I've tried several code's but none of them will work.
Here are some examples:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var professional = $("#professional");
  var oldValue = professional.val();
  professional.data("oldValue", oldValue);
  
  $("#professional").change(function(){
    var oldValue = $(this).data("oldValue");
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if (newValue > oldValue)
        alert("increase!");
     else
         alert("decrease!");
    $(this).data("oldValue", newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <label for="professional">Professional</label><br>
  <input type="number" class="price" id="professional" min="0" value="9">
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#professional").attr('data-prev-val', $("#professional").val());
  $("#professional").change(function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if (newValue > $(this).attr('data-prev-val'))
      alert("increase!");
    else
      alert("decrease!");

    $("#professional").attr('data-prev-val', newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <label for="professional">Professional</label><br>
  <input type="number" class="price" id="professional" min="0" value="9">
</div>
```

There are other ways, but they all have the same problem. Does anyone know why this is and how it can be solved?

Comment: It's because you're comparing the value alphabetically rather than numerically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're comparing the value alphabetically rather than numerically

try this:

```
var oldValue = Number($(this).data("oldValue"));
var newValue = Number($(this).val());
if (newValue > oldValue) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `parseInt` because currently value consider as string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#professional").attr('data-prev-val', $("#professional").val());
  $("#professional").change(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (newValue > parseInt($(this).attr('data-prev-val')))
      alert("increase!");
    else
      alert("decrease!");

    $("#professional").attr('data-prev-val', newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <label for="professional">Professional</label><br>
  <input type="number" class="price" id="professional" min="0" value="9">
</div>
```